# How to add more variables js vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, variables

code below

```js
methods: {
switch (typwik) {
  case 'T':
    console.log('<span class="ui green label"><i class="check icon"></i>TOMATO!</span>');
    break;
  case 'N':
    console.log('<span class="ui red label"><i class="x icon"></i>NASA!</span>');
    break;
  case 'U':
    console.log('<span class="ui red label"><i class="x icon"></i>UGANDA!</span>');
    break;
}
}
```

how to change this code to make it work after entering more than two values, for example: if I type T it will show "Tomato" if I type N it will show "NASA" and if I type U it will show "Uganda". At the moment it only works on two variables, if I type T it displays something and if I type something other than T it displays a different option.

Comment: Take a look at the [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement, it might help you further

Comment: Add switch in computed method     `switch (sky) {
  case "red":
    console.log("Uh oh.");
    break;
  case "blue":
    console.log("A good day for golf!");
    break;
  default:
    console.log("Try looking up for a hint.");
}`

Comment: @Reyno could you please help me?

Comment: it doesnt work, this code need to be placed into methods vue

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* doesnt help anyone. Please update your question with what you've tried -> [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Reyno code updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close, you just need to combine both of your attempts. In the first one you look at the `value` and `return` based on its outcome. While in the second you use a `switch` but you're not returning anything.

```
typwik: function(value) {
  switch (value) {
    case 'T':
      return '<span class="ui green label"><i class="check icon"></i>TOMATO!</span>';
    case 'N':
      return '<span class="ui red label"><i class="x icon"></i>NASA!</span>';
    case 'U':
      return '<span class="ui red label"><i class="x icon"></i>UGANDA!</span>';
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a computed property with a object for that, like this:

```
const names = {
    A: "Awesome",
    T: "Tomato",
    N: "Nasa",
};

var search = 'T';

return names[search] || 'Not found';
```

Take a look at this functional example that I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-butterfly-xsc67i?file=/src/App.vue:286-372

This way is more easy to mantain and more clean instead using a switch case;